# Is it possible to develop a web-application using the JavaFX API?

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, web-applications, javafx

I have developed standalone applications with JavaFX and its impressive. I want to use these features in a web application also, for something like Dashboard generation. I have been thinking off-late if it is at all possible.Help,comments or suggestions of any sort is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three ways:

- JavaFX Applet: This would match what you ask, I think, but [Applets/ Browser Plugins are discontinued by Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)
- Java Web Start: The application wouldn't run in the browser but can be started from a link in the browser.
- [CaptainCasa](http://www.captaincasa.com/): I haven't tried it, but AFAIK, they use JavaFX as the rendering part for JSF pages.